# Syncing a very out-of-date github repository

Tags: git

I have a massive github repository that has fallen badly out of sync. I have about 100 MB of source files (that should be pushed) and ~10 TB of data (that should not be pushed).

I have done

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Resync'
```

but then I noticed many files that should not be pushed have been added to the commit. I added these files to my `.gitignore` file, but now when I do those above lines again, it seems that nothing is added except the new `.gitignore` file.

I think I am supposed to do

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

but I am terrified of losing all of my work in the last year. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You should always check what was staged before you commit. Then you would have been able to fix the files that should not have been added.

Comment: @crashmstr how can I do that?

Comment: @crashmstr and how can I fix it now?

Comment: You can check the status with `git status` both before and after you `add`. You can't just blindly `add`/`commit` back to back and expect to not have any problems or mistakes. Once you commit, you can roll back or amend, but still: checking to make sure you are adding and committing the right files and the right file contents is the only real solution.

Comment: As to how to fix: that depends on if you pushed to a public repository or not (and how painful it will be to anyone else).

Comment: @crashmstr I have not yet pushed. Painful to no one else - I am the only one who commits to this repository

Comment: Reset the commit to the previous, keeping contents. Then update the `.gitignore`, `add` the correct files, *verify everything*, then commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't pushed the commit yet.  You can undo it via `git reset HEAD~`.  This will undo the commit and you can add the files properly.

Comment: And it will not change any of my local files?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  It will move the repo back to commit before the one you made.  If you do a `git status` the files should show as changed but not staged for commit.

Comment: Here's an easy way to be 100% sure that your files will not be touched: Move `.git` out of the source directory, and for peace of mind stick it in an empty folder elsewhere. Then it _can't_ touch your uncommitted files. (It could try to check everything back out if you give the wrong command, though.) When you're done, put `.git` back where it belongs.

Comment: >"It will move the repo back to commit before the one you made" I'm not exactly sure I understand that. The commit before the one I made was a year ago with very different files. I guess it will only move some kind of pointer, and not actually resync everything to that old commit?

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron - to understand what reset does, you need to understand the multiple storage areas in git - work tree, index (staging areas), database.  Any reset updates `HEAD` (a pointer into the database) and the current branch if you're not in detached head mode.  A "mixed" reset (the default) also updates the index.  Only a "hard" reset would update the working tree.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I think I got it all sorted now. Major headache relieved.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have locally committed things, and are worried about losing work, start by creating a tag for the "bad" commit.  When all is corrected you can delete the tag, but in the mean time you can always get back to where you are.

```
git tag bad_commit
# try some things, but oops, the work tree ends up corrupted
git checkout bad_commit
# carry on
```

That's just a safety net; the odds are nothing you're going to do will cost you your local state anyway.  But precautions against the odd condition you forget to think about never hurts.

To that end: you also might want to make sure that the commit contains *everything* about your local state.

```
git status --ignored
```

should report "nothing to commit, working tree clean" and should *not* list any files as "ignored".

Which is counter-intuitive, because you have files in gitignore.  As you've discovered, git's ignore rules only apply to untracked files, so it isn't ignoring the files it already knows about (even though they match gitignore patterns).

If it's ok to have those files added to the repo and then deleted in the subsequent commit, then you can

```
git rm --cached files.that.should.have.been.ignored
```

and because of the `--cached` keyword it *will not* affect your worktree copies.  These files will become untracked in the current staging area (for the next commit) and so the ignore rules will filter them out.

Or if you want to clean it up "like it never happened", as long as you haven't pushed the bad commit, you can use git reset

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^
```

(assuming the bad commit is the most recent one).  Note I'm recommending a *mixed* reset, because this will leave your work tree alone.  From here you would re-stage what *should* be committed (including the `.gitignore` file) and proceed from there.  And actually since no changes are staged and the `.gitignore` is present

```
git add .
```

should work this time (though using `git status` to double-check is a good idea).

Another option is to do a *soft* reset instead of a *mixed* one, in which case your previous staging work will remain in effect / ready to commit again.  In that case you'll have to `git rm --cached` the files you *don't* want to commit.  (And you still need to make sure the ignore file is staged.)